# MVC model binding for bootstrap button group

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have bootstrap 'button' input group in my form

```
<div class="btn-group type-select pull-left top-buffer add-on" id="typeOrderSelect">
    <a class="btn btn-primary popover-default" data-content="Car" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-car fa-lg"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary popover-default" data-content="Bike" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-motorcycle fa-lg"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary popover-default" data-content="Truck" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-truck fa-lg"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

[image]

and now I want bind it to a existing model. how do I do it? Because technically it's just html links. Only idea I have right now is creating a hidden field and when user clicks `<a>` link then through JS I enter certain data into hidden field (simple radio button field).

What are your thoughts? Thanks.

update:
when user clicks car, bike, or truck he changes property and then after submiting the form i would like to receive this property on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `<a>` links, you should use `<input>` radio buttons and `<label>`s and bind the name of these radios to your property.

In your model, let's say you have

```
public string Selection { get; set; }
```

Then your view should be

```
<div class="btn-group type-select pull-left top-buffer add-on" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="Selection" value="Car">
        <i class="fa fa-car fa-lg"></i>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
         <input type="radio" name="Selection" value="Bike">
         <i class="fa fa-motorcycle fa-lg"></i>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" name="Selection" value="Truck">
          <i class="fa fa-truck fa-lg"></i>
    </label>
</div>
```

This reproduces the following: (The Bike is checked)

[image: Radio Buttons]

When you submit your form, your `Selection` property would be `"Bike"`

Comment: thanks man. as simple as right. sometimes i think i complicate my life by myself.

Answer (score 0):

*Ok, I've changed my answer, as I misunderstand question in first place.*

Generally you have two option:

1. JavaSctipt like you suggest, it's easy solution, and it's ok if you already use JS on your page.
2. Stylized radio buttons using CSS. You can change visual appearance of your 'radios' using only CSS and no need JS. It's more compatibility solution.
   It's a lot of examples how to do this - here is one of them: 
   [CSS Styling Radio Button and Checkboxes](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/css-radio-button-checkbox-background/).

Of course radio button will be automatically bind to Model, just set proper `id` (different for each input) and `name` (the same for each input), for example:

```
 <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="content" value="Car" />
 <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="content" value="Bike" />
 <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="content" value="Truck" />
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants to post the form when the user clicks on a button, instead, he wants a property to change when the user clicks on any them.

Comment: hmm... probably my misunderstanding ;) for me 'binding to model'. 'hidden input' and 'radio button' suggest that finally you will send your data somewhere.

Comment: in that case like you said - OP can use JS like himself suggest or hi can simply use radio buttons stylized by CSS (hi consider radio button as solution).

Comment: Exacltly GeorgeChond. This is what i want.

Comment: when user clicks car, bike, or truck he changes property and then after submiting the form i would like to receive this property on the server. sorry Lukasx Makovej, this is my bad i think i'm not fully described my issue.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, I've changed my answer, as I misunderstand question in first place.